# Задача "Сколько шестерок?"

Tags: python, оптимизация

Условие:
Сколько раз будет использована цифра **`6`**, если подряд записать последовательные натуральные числа от **`a`** до **`b`**?

Входные данные:
Два натуральных числа `a и b (1 ≤ a, b ≤ 10^9)`.

Исходные данные:
Число цифр **`6`** в последовательных натуральных числах `от a до b`
.

**`Лимит времени 1 сек`**

Мой код выгледит так:

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
count = 0

for i in range(a, b+1):
    if '6' in str(i):
        count+=str(i).count('6')

print(count)
```

Но он превышает лимит времени.
Как его ускорить?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Подумайте, сколько шестерок содержится в первом десятке чисел, в первой сотне, в первой тысяче и так далее.

Comment: Перебор до миллиарда - это уже долго, да плюс ещё str операция не быстрая, так что перебор не подойдёт, тут только думать над математическим вычислением.

Comment: Ну, либо можно попробовать побитовые операции

Comment: Сколько будет шестёрок в разряде единиц? (Это не сложно). Сколько шестёрок будет в разряде десятков? (Это чуть-чуть сложнее). Сколько в разряде сотен и старше? (Теперь это совсем просто).